# How can i process a multiple files from a file field in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, filefield

I am trying to figure out how to process multiple files from a filefield in Django. I have figured out how to add the "multiple" attribute to the form field. What I need to do now is loop through each file and perform some logic.

I have a form with fields like this (in views.py):

```
class RecipientListForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField()
recipients = forms.CharField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':"James Jameson, james.jameson@aol.com"}),
    label="Paste recipient information (comma-separated, in 'name, email' format)")

recipients_file = RecipientsFileField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple':"true"}),
    label="Or upload a .csv file in 'name, email' format (max size %dMB)" % RecipientsFileField.MAX_FILESIZE_MB)

def __init__(self, account, recipient_list=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RecipientListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.account = account
    self.recipient_list = recipient_list

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

RecipientsFileField looks like this (also in views.py):

```
class RecipientsFileField(forms.FileField):
MAX_FILESIZE_MB = 30

def validate(self, value):
    super(RecipientsFileField, self).validate(value)
    if not value: return

    fname = value.name

    if (value.content_type not in (('text/csv',) + EXCEL_MIMETYPES) or not re.search(r'\.(xlsx?|csv)$', fname, re.I)):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please upload a .csv or .xlsx file')

    if value.size >= self.MAX_FILESIZE_MB * 1024 * 1024:
        raise forms.ValidationError('File must be less than %dMB' % (self.MAX_FILESIZE_MB,))
```

I have tried to perform my logic in the `clean` method of `RecipientListForm` but I have only been able to access the first file that is uploaded, it seems that the other files are not uploaded. I have looked at the docs but the way these forms are setup don't seem to be reflected in the documentation about forms, unless I am just looking in the wrong place. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files), you should be able to get the files from the request object with:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('recipients_file')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - where would you suggest i do this given the code i provided above?